# BelongsTo with ExtJS Model

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I have two Models: "Identity" and "Profile". The identity 'belongsTo' profile. When I get a record of type 'identity', I want to (by this record) get the correspondent profile. I'm trying using the following code:

```
Ext.define('App.model.Identity', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
            // ...
            {name: 'id_profile',  type: 'int'},
            // ...
            ],

    belongsTo: {
        model: 'App.model.Profile',
        primaryKey: 'id',
        foreignKey: 'id_profile',
        associatedName: 'Profile'
    },

    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        api: {
            read: App.Config.getBaseUrl() + '/admin_identity/list',
            create: App.Config.getBaseUrl() + '/admin_identity/create',
            update: App.Config.getBaseUrl() + '/admin_identity/update',
            destroy: App.Config.getBaseUrl() + '/admin_identity/destroy'
        },
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'data'
        }
    }
});

Ext.define('App.model.Profile', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
            {name: 'id',  type: 'int'},
            // ...
            ],

    belongsTo: {
        model: 'App.model.Identity',
        primaryKey: 'id',
        foreignKey: 'id_profile',
        name: 'identities'
    },

    proxy: {
        // ...
    }
});
```

When I try to do this:

```
function viewProfile(identity) {
    identity.getProfile(function(profile){
        console.log(profile);
    });
}
```

What I get is an empty profile's object. The strange thing is that the Identity class didn't do any http request to get the profile. I'm doing this right?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
identity.getProfile({
    success:function(profile, operation){
    },
    failure: function(profile, operation){
        //check for a failure
    }
});
```

I would also try removing the associatedName property.

Comment: The associatedName property is used to generate the getters and setters. this way I can call 'modelObject.getProfile' (originally, I need to call get{modelname}). The solution you proposed didn't work. The callback isn't called.

Comment: here is. I added to the question only for Identity model, the Profile model has almost the same proxy. App.. baseUrl is a function already defined, just to help me with URLs.